# Why is my Azure SQL Elastic Query CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL failing on "WITH Identity"?

Tags: sql-server, azure, t-sql

I am trying to create an external table to be able to elastic query across databases on my Azure SQL server.  I am following the steps outlined in:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-query-getting-started-vertical and https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6445/azure-sql-cross-database-query/.

After creating the master key

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '<master_key_password>';
```

I then try to create the Database Scoped Credential that I am going to use to access the server for the external database.

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL = ElasticDBQueryCred
WITH IDENTITY = '<username I use to login to server>',
SECRET = '<password I use to login to server>';
```

The error then pops up on IDENTITY that says

> Incorrect syntax near 'IDENTITY'. Expecting CREATEDBOPT_BACKUPSTORAGEREDUNDANCY, CREATEDBOPT_CATALOGCOLLATION, CREATEDBOPT_FILESTREAM, CREATEDBOPT_LOGAPPLY, CREATEDBOPT_OTHER, or CREATEDBOPT_PERSISTENT_LOG_BUFFER

There is nothing in the documentation about this.

Comment: Extra `=` after the word `CREDENTIAL` see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b52ce45a585cb0eaada9e860fdca8634 and [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-scoped-credential-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax)

Comment: Without the ```=``` there, an error appears that says ```Incorrect syntax near 'ElasticDBQueryCred'. Expecting '='```.  But even on removing it, the original ```IDENTITY``` error remains.

Comment: Possibly relevant https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/96ef5863-9310-4c33-ac04-4cc3696c31c6/unable-to-compile-sqlproj-when-i-add-a-quotscoped-credentialquot?forum=ssdt Are you sure it actually doesn't run or is it just the IDE complaining with red marks?